# C++ use enum from different template class as function parameter

Tags: c++, templates, enums

I got two template classes `CarOwner` and `Truck`.

```
// CarOwner.h
#include "Truck.h"
template<size_t T1, typename T2>
class CarOwner {
public:
    enum MyEnum {
        red = 0,
        green
    }

   void DoSomething();

private:
   Truck<DataContainer<T1,T2>> truck_;   
   MyEnum color;
}

// CarOwner.hpp
template<size_t T1, typename T2>
void CarOwner<T1,T2>::DoSomething(){
    this->truck_.setEnum(this->color);
}

// Truck.h
template<typename G>
class Truck {
    void setEnum(CarOwner<T1,T2>::MyEnum color); // <---
}
```

My problem is to understand how to write the function declaration of `void setEnum();`. As shown in the code above I actually want to pass the function an enum of type `CarOwner<T1,T2>::MyEnum color`. As I need to `#include "Truck.h"` in class `CarOwner`, I can't include the `CarOwner` in the `Truck` class. Furthermore, the template parameters `T1` and `T2` are unknown inside class `Truck` as it has a different template type `G`.

I have no clue how to properly declare this function to accept the `CarOwner<T1,T2>::MyEnum`. Any help is appreciated!

**Edit:** 
template parameter `G` is a combination of `T1` and `T2`.

This code is just an example to state my problem and the design obviously is odd.

Comment: This seems like an odd design. Why would the car *owner* have a color?

Comment: `DoSomething` must be declared in `CarOwner` body first. `Truck truck_;` is not going to work because `Truck` is a template, so you will need to pass `G` as an extra `CarOwner`  template parameter. `setEnum` need to be a template as well.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I really want to avoid to add an extra template parameter to `CarOwner`. Wouldn't it possible to somehow forward declare the `CarOwner` in `Truck`?

Comment: if "template parameter G is a combination of T1 and T2" then you may be able to write a partial specialization of Truck to extract T1 and T2..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming Truck is instantiated as `Truck<DataContainer<T1,T2>>`, you can write a partial specialization:

```
template<typename G>
class Truck {
    // whatever
};

template<typename T1,typename T2>
class CarOwner;

template<typename T1, typename T2>
class Truck<DataContainer<T1,T2>> {
    void setEnum( typename CarOwner<T1,T2>::MyEnum color );
};
```

alternatively, you could templatize setEnum over, say, OwnerType:

```
template<typename G>
class Truck {
  template<typename OwnerType>
  void setEnum( typename OwnerType::MyEnum color);
};

// ...

void CarOwner<T1,T2>::DoSomething(){
  this->truck_.template setEnum<CarOwner<T1,T2>>(this->color);
}
```

or ...

Comment: I didn't even know you could templatize setEnum! Thank you so much, works like a charm!